# Custom Client Side Validation in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, validation, model-view-controller, client, partial-views

i am fairly new to MVC so i need help in making a custom client side unobtrusive validation. Here's the scenario,

I have made a partial view form which gets loaded in a div through ajax in which student can enter their details which gets submitted to a DB. I have implemented a **required** validation on field **Name** which runs perfectly. Now i want to make a custom validation to check whether the input in the field **Contact number** is a mobile number or not (*By checking string length is equal to 10 or not*). Need your guys help in  checking out where have i done wrong since the validation does fired but no error message is displayed (*plus the partial view unloads itself from div when validation for **Contact Number** fails*).

P.S :- For learning purpose i have decided to write custom validation to check string length so whether there is an inbuilt validation for one or not, it doesn't matter.

1.Custom Validation.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class is10DigitAttribute:ValidationAttribute,IClientValidatable
    {
        string contactNumber;
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            contactNumber = value.ToString();
            if(contactNumber.Length != 10)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Please Enter a correct Mobile number");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
            rule.ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a correct Mobile number";
            rule.ValidationType = "checkstringlength";

            yield return rule;
        }
    }
}
```

2.Partial View Form

```
<link href="~/Content/ViewRight.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@model TestApplication.Models.StudentTable


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $("document").ready(function () {

        $.validator.addMethod("checkstringlength", function (value) {
            alert(value);
            return value.val().length == 10;

        }, 'Please Enter a correct mobile number');

        $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("checkstringlength");

    });




    function reset() {

        $("#confirm").css("display", "block");
        $("form").clearForm();

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#confirm").css("display", "none");
        }, 2000);
    };




</script>


 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Default", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="POST", OnSuccess="reset" }))
 { 

    <div id="main">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <h1>Right Partial View</h1>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.ID, "ID")
                </div>
                  @Html.TextBox("ID")
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Name, "Name")
                </div>
                @Html.EditorFor(t => t.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Name)
                @*@Html.TextBox("Name")*@
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Age, "Age")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Age")
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Contact_Number, "Contact Number")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Contact_Number")

            <li>
                <div class="label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(t => t.Division, "Division")
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Division")
            </li>
        </ol>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <br /><br />
        <span id="confirm" style="display:none; color:red">Record Entered Sucessfully!!</span>
    </div>

 }
```

StudentTable.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    public class StudentTable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter a Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        [is10Digit]
        public string Contact_Number { get; set; }

        public string Division { get; set; }

    }
}
```